# Passing data from JavaScript to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Wellcome!

I have a problem with passing data from JavaScript to MVC Controller. Im new to MVC so I probably miss something.

```
$("#example").keypress(function (event) {
    var data = "example";
    $.ajax({
        url: "/example/example",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { example: data },
        success: function (example) {
            var items = "";
            $.each(data, function (i, example) {
                items += "<option>" + example + "</option>";
            });
            $("#example").html(items);
        }
    });
});

public class PeoplePickerController : BaseController
{
    // GET: PeoplePicker
    public ActionResult PeoplePicker(object data)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            IQueryable logins = (IQueryable)QueryDatabaseForUsersAndGroups((string)data, Context.Users);

            return Json(new SelectList(example, "example"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return PartialView();
    }
```

}

data parameter is always null.

Comment: You don't pass a parameter named `data`. The url does not match your method, but assuming that's a typo, you parameter needs to be `string example`. And it should be `type: "GET",`

Comment: Could you please give me a code example? It wolud be very helpful.

Comment: In order to hit the controller you have shown it  needs to be `url: '@Url.Action("PeoplePicker", "PeoplePicker")',` and the method needs to be `public ActionResult PeoplePicker(string example) {`

Comment: The JS line "data: { example: data }," should actually be "data: { data: data }," because the variable in your controller method is called "data". I'd change the type of that variable from "object" to "string"